# Need to measure currents in the range of 1 μA to 100 μA with protection against high voltage sparks in the range of milli amps

Tags: current-measurement, high-voltage

My experimental setup typically results in DC current in the range of 0.1 μA to 100 μA. However, there is a fair chance of discharge happening due to dielectric breakdown occasionally which might result in current spurts in the order above milliamps. I need to use an ammeter to measure current and then log data into my PC using a USB interface. I have faced issues purchasing nano ammeters and microammeters as they do not withstand such high currents even for a very short interval. Is there any possibility to measure current in such a wide range or to protect the ammeter against the current spurts which I need not measure?

Comment: 'current spurts' - that's colorful technical language! Normally one would have a diode or zener diode to clamp the maximum voltage to the metering system.

Comment: Add in a schematic (there's a button on the editor toolbar), show your shunt resistance value and your voltage source value so we know what the largest "spurt" might be.

Comment: What is the frequency if these currents you are measuring? If you say "DC" you can add a lowpass filter to smooth out the spike, making it easier to filter. If it's high frequency signals, then no. So?

Comment: Yes, it is DC current. I have edited my question. I have not thought of using an LPF to get rid of the discharge currents. I think the problem arises as this discharge current persists for a longer time scale before it dies down.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Discharge or PD is the phenomena of a dielectric ionizing and changing from a good insulator to a good conductor. When this cascades thru the entire insulation to across the source in AC you would have a grid fault but in oil transformers, it just detonates some oil molecules in hydrogen. In air it creates ozone. For DC it would act like an SCR crowbar.

A current meter has a maximum rating determines by the shunt resistance. So to protect that you must have an OVP that works faster than the ionization which can be slow to reach threshold of breakdown in microseconds but fast with negative resistance in nano or pico seconds depending on the RC negative incremental resistance = tau time constant.

This means an MOV cannot protect it when the PD occurs unless you had some inductance and capacitance in circuit to reduce the rise time across the shunt. That implies you must clamp the overvoltage before it breaks down by knowing the BDV threshold in advance.

All PD occurs in all dielectrics due to ionic contamination such that the ions have lower particle BDV than the surrounding medium. As you know, a series of dielectric capacitors will have the greatest voltage drop across the smallest capacitor. This is why PD occurs just before a total insulation break down voltage (BDV).  This can be measured on a Le Croy DSO and the more contamination the wider std deviation or variance of the BDV.  If the BDV is exactly the same on every test, this is an indication of extremely low contamination which is unavoidable as there exists no perfect insulation, yet some are far better than others.

Answer (score 1):

> My experimental setup typically results in DC current in the range of 0.1 μA to 100 μA.

So you need a protection circuit with **low leakage current**.

And you can use a lowpass filter.

A solution would be a LC lowpass filter, using a ferrite bead as the inductor, to limit the rate of current rise to something "civilized". Then, something to limit voltage with low leakage current. Since Zeners leak a lot more than low leakage diodes, the latter should be a better option.

[image]

Set "vmin" and "vmax" to the min and max voltages that won't blow your ammeter. If one of the wires is ground, you only need one circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The device you are looking for is a [transient-voltage suppression diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode). They work like zener diodes, safely clamping the voltage while dissipating the energy of the transient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not an analog front-end circuits designer I suggest you to buy a digital multimeter with an USB interface.

Multimeters that cost 300 USD or above have the protection circuitry you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your valuable suggestions. Just a while ago, I found a research paper that answers this question. The solution presented in it looks like a combination of the solutions which all of you proposed.

[Spark protection circuit for measuring current in high-voltage circuits](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030438860400213X)